flutter web make invalid path error when using realtime database emulator
I'm working with flutter and realtime database emulator.
When i try to read from database by using .get() following error occur.

Error: child failed: path argument was an invalid path = "http://hostNumber.0.0.1:4000/database/projectName/data/". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"

Since this is path error I can't do anything about it but no one seems to have same issue. Please teach me how to fix this issue.
I'm working on flutter web which might be a cause but could not find clear statement that realtime db emulator won't work on web.
firebase_options.dart are made with flutterfire, firebase emulators are all set up, from error message I can confirm that path is pointing to realtime database emulators.

Ny feeling is that you're passing the emulator URL to the wrong API call, but it's impossible to be certain without seeing a minimal repro. Please edit your question to include this.

as frank pointed out in the comment I was putting path to realtime database at a wrong place, to be specific at a reference path.
Correct way to connect python and realtime database was by using credentials.Certificate and write url for databaseURL when initializing app.
cred = credentials.Certificate("servicekey.json")
app = initialize_app(cred, {'databaseURL': 'http://host.0.0.1:9000/?ns=projectName'})
test = db.reference('test').get()

